# Redirect Legacy Post to ServiceStack API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that is running ServiceStack v3.9.71. I have a new ServiceStack API that is configured to be available at `~/api/*` but need to redirect POST requests from old locations `~/service/*` to the new API however I am coming unstuck.

I've tried using url redirects but in doing so the `POST` becomes a `GET` and the POST data is lost.

```
<rule name="GetVenuesByLocation" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^service/getvenuelistbylocation/$" />
    <action redirectType="Temporary" type="Redirect" url="/api/VenueListByLocation" />
</rule>
```

Can this be achieved and if so could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Simon

Comment: You can simply proxy the request at the old URI to the new URI with a server-side HttpClient call.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or the Network tab in your browser's developer toolbar to make sure a HTTP 307 is happening when you visit `/service/getvenuelistbylocation.` According to (IIS 6) [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2175ec7d-b2a9-4f2c-821a-b6539b88902e.mspx?mfr=true) and (IIS 7) [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770393%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) HTTP 307 Temporary Redirects the Web Browser should reissue the POST with the data.

Comment: @paaschpa It seems that for some reason a 301 Redirect occurs before the 307 which might explain the loss of post values. But why the 301? The result is a a 301 followed by a 307 followed by a 404. The 404 is thrown because there is no action for the GET request.

Comment: What tool (browser, Fiddler, etc) are you using to see the 301 > 307 > 404. Asking because browsers will cache 301 redirects...see [IE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/possible-bug-in-ie-with-http-code-301-permanent/33cd03f0-8c82-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5), [Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects) so that could be a potential issue with your test(s).

Comment: I am seeing it in Fiddler when I attempt to post to the old url.

Comment: @paaschpa You're right about the 307 redirect pass through the POST values. Do you want to add that as answer rather than the comments? The reason for the 301 redirect first is because of a seperate rule to force trailing slashes. I can't quite get my regex to make the trailing slash optional in this instance ```<match url="^service/getvenuelistbylocation/?$" />```

Comment: ...and it turns out that the rule is correct but needed to be added before the rule which forces trailing slashes. It then works with or without the trailing slash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer and discussion within comments. Adding answer to make it easier for others to find solution.**

The Temporary rewrite rule (within the question) is correct and will do a 307 POST maintaining the original values.

The issue was an already existing Redirect rewrite rule was creating a 301 prior to hitting the Temporary rewrite rule. The 301 would lose the data.

**Per ProNotion** - it turns out that the rule is correct but needed to be added before the rule which forces trailing slashes. It then works with or without the trailing slash!